# C# WinForms showing a control as a dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu

Gretings

I need to have a custom control for my application. Basically its an expression editing GUI. You have, say, expression:

```
If variable_x is greater than variable_y
```

And you can click on "greater than" and change it to other comparator (like, equal to or less than).

The control thus must look like a label, but when you click it, it must show a dropdown (like combobox does) that has a listview inside (or maybe some other control) so that user can choose something. In a sense, i need a combobox without the box itself, replaced by something else (in this case, a label).

I know how to make custom controls, i understand i must somehow DropDown on mouse click or enter keypress, and hook events so that when whatever i dropped has closed, the choice is made, and also somehow track if user clicked elsewhere so i can close this dropdowned control. But i dont know if this is easy to do (some built-in method exists) or i have to do it all myself? Dont want to redevelop the wheel....

Please tell me if there are easy ways to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have the possibility to change to WPF, then I suggest you to do so. With WPF you could build this kind of DropDownList easier than with WinForms. If not, then the question is what reason do you have not to use just the built-in DropDownList? Your task sounds like it is very far from "usual" UI behavior and might be more confusing to users.

Comment: 3 labels. In middle one is your "greater then" text and add to that label context menu strip and you need to change behavior to show it on left mouse click.

Comment: Yeah i guess i'm better off tweaking the ContextMenuStrip. Btw how do i use DropDownList in WinForms, it doesnt appear in the list of possible controls in the toolbox for me

Comment: The control is named "ComboBox". After putting it onto your Form you can then change the value of the property "DropDownStyle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the `ComboBox` control to update the `DropDownStyle` on `Enter` and `LostFocus` events.

```
public partial class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        this.SelectionChangeCommitted += this.OnComboBoxSelectionChangeCommitted;
        this.Enter += this.OnControlEnter;
        this.LostFocus += this.OnComboBoxLostFocus;
    }

    private void OnControlEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    }

    private void OnComboBoxLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.Simple;
    }

    private void OnComboBoxSelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Notify to update other controls that depend on the combo box value
    }
}
```